# Fixed position div in HTML sitting in front of background image of secondary div

Tags: html, css

I'm looking for an HTML/CSS solution for the following issue.

I currently have a sidebar-type element on the left side of my webpage. On the right side I want to place several panels of information. I want these panels of information to resize themselves according to the size of the window, while remaining to the right of the sidebar. I want to set individual backgrounds for all of these panels to give each of them a unique feel (think of a PowerPoint, but better).

In order to accomplish all of this, I've set a fixed div as a sidebar on the site that has to be exactly 92px wide. I also have several divs to the right of this fixed div. I need to have the "panel" divs on the right side resize themselves according to the viewport width, so currently I'm making their width 100% of the screen. To make sure that the background images fit within the "panel" divs no matter what their size, I'm using the `background-size:contain;` line.

Everything works perfectly, except for one thing: the "panel" divs sit underneath the fixed div and the background images for these divs are cut off. I've made a JSFiddle to emphasize this point: http://jsfiddle.net/32yZL/

You'll notice that the three lines of text that read "This is a test. This is a test. This is a test." are cut off on the left. This is easily fixed by adding 92px of padding to the div, but I've haven't been able to find a similar solution for the background images of the "panel" divs.

Any suggestions?

EDIT: Thanks everyone for your replies. I've tried them all but none of them worked, which I believe to be my fault. I didn't know that JSFiddle could import external files (yea, I know, I'm blind) and I've created a new one that I hope emphasizes the problem a littler better:

http://jsfiddle.net/ChrisBush/womLk4c9/

You'll notice that the background image for the div is still behind the sidebar, but the text is fine. I want that background image to sit flush against the sidebar. Any suggestions?

EDIT 2: After working more on this project I've begun to realize that there are several solutions to this issue. Unfortunately, I'm using some free js that I pulled from sites across the web to create a visual effect on the site, which is complicating things well beyond the scope of this post and rendering most of your answers irrelevant. I think I'm going to try to rewrite some of the js, and for that I'm going to make another post elsewhere. Thanks again for all your suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/32yZL/4/

I wrapped the right side slides in a `<div id="slide_wrap">` which I gave a `margin-left: 92px;`.

This will keep them from going under your fixed sidebar.

EDIT: In response to your code edit, this issue isn't that it is under the sidebar, it's that the background is positioned fixed. If you removed the `fixed` from your background declaration, this fixes it.

Comment: I really like the way you approached this, and I tried using it, but I don't think I was very clear on my issue. If you have the time would you mind taking a look at the edit I posted?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use the width: 100% on slide01, just use a margin-left: 92px on slide01 and remove width and you are done http://jsfiddle.net/32yZL/6/, a div element tries to use all the horizontal space it can use by default, setting it to 100% usually gives more problems than solutions if you need to set margins and paddings too

```
#slide01{
    background:red no-repeat fixed;
    background-size:contain;
    margin-left: 92px;
    height:250px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by first floating the panel div to the right and then using the calc method for the width

```
width: calc(100% - 92px);
```

and just subtract the width of the sidebar from 100% width.

Here is an updated [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/32yZL/3/)

Hope that is what you are looking for.